# How do I create a "primed" list in MS Word with no automatic apostrophes?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013, list, numbering

I have a 2013 MS Word document with a list like

> (a) kangaroos
> (b) camels

I would like to add an additional list to my document, with the item letters distinguished from those of the first list using apostrophes, or "primes," like

> (a') koalas
> (b') capybaras

Initially, doing this seems easy enough.  I type and highlight "koalas", go to Home > Numbering > Define New Number Format, and add an apostrophe between the "a" and the ")".  However, if I then press Enter after "koalas" and type "capybaras", I obtain an erroneous ' just before capybaras:

> (a') koalas
> (b') 'capybaras

I can manually delete this unwanted ', but is there a way to keep it from appearing in the first place?

(This example is simplified.  I am working with many such instances, so a preventative solution would be useful.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with MSWord 2021, I get the same effect with single and double quotes:

```
(a')koalas
(b')'capybaras

(a")koalas
(b")"capybaras
```

but not with other characters (I didn't try them all). Note that is doesn't capitalise the first letter as it does with other numbering schemes.

It was possible to remove this effect by going to the `Options`  then `Proofing`, then `AutoCorrect Options` and untick in the `Auto Format` tab `Replace` section:

`'Straight' quotes with smart "quotes"`

To makes things more interesting, the same option is also in the `Auto format as you type` tab, this time in the `Replace as you type` tab:

`'Straight' quotes with smart "quotes"`